# Simple custom play button for several songs in HTML

Tags: html, audio, button

All I want to do is post several songs on my page where the user presses a custom image that I created. I don't want to use Flash since I want this to work on the iPad and iPhone. But I want to create a cute play button as opposed to the standard console.

Thanks!!!

Comment: You need to provide a lot more detail in your question. We can't help you blindfolded.

Comment: hmmm Ok.....I want to make buttons, the user clicks them, and music plays. I don't want to use Flash or HTML5. I want to do this using HTML/Javascript as I want it to work on iphones and ipads.

Comment: Have a look at the HTML5 [`<audio> tag`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Element/Audio).

Comment: Will HTML5 work in a regular old HTML page? I've tried but it doesn't seem to work. But I could be missing something.

Comment: It will only work with browsers that support HTML5. It "works" with older browsers, however your audio tag won't as it's not supported in HTML4.x

Comment: Any other options for just straight up HTML?

Comment: Unfortunately not. You'd have to use Flash, or perhaps Silverlight if you were targeting IE only. Mobile devices support HTML5 pretty well, and all recent versions of desktop browsers are compatible too. You just need to be wary of IE and users with older browsers.

Comment: Luckily I found a work around with working the play button into an image in the background. Now I'm just trying to get the best audio format that work cross platform. I'm running into issues with mp3s!

thanks for the help.

Comment: I use jPlayer for that kind of stuff (http://jplayer.org). It's jQuery using native HTML5 and Flash as a fallback,  it really works on all platforms, and you can tweak the graphics any way you want (yes, that's a lot of work, but IMO worth doing it)

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/3UXDH/1/).
It uses the HTML5 `audio` tags

HTML

```
<a onclick="this.firstChild.play()" class="button">
   <audio src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Tromboon-sample.ogg">
   </audio>
&#9658;</a>​
```

This works for as many audio files as you want to play. See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/3UXDH/2/) that takes multiple sources.

See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/3UXDH/3/) that has been updated for aesthetics.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`AUDIO`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Element/Audio) element for modern browsers. For IE8 and older you can try to utilize [`BGSOUND`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/bgsound) element and/or Flash fallback.

Answer (score 0):

here's an example of how to trigger audio playback via custom icon images.. this method uses jPlayer so is cross-platform.. test it on this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/75lb/XPkTz/

example markup:

```
<div id="audio"></div>
<a href="http://www.freesfx.co.uk/rx2/mp3s/3/2665_1315685839.mp3">
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/creative-freedom/shimmer/48/Play-icon.png" />
</a>
<a href="http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-07-Bubble.mp3">
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/creative-freedom/shimmer/48/Play-icon.png" />
</a>
```

​and script:

```
$("#audio").jPlayer({
    swfPath: "http://www.jplayer.org/latest/js/Jplayer.swf",
    supplied: "mp3"
});

$("a").click(function(e) {
    $("#audio").jPlayer("setMedia", { 
        mp3: this.href 
    }).jPlayer("play");

    e.preventDefault();
});
​
```

don't forget to ensure you have jQuery and jPlayer loaded on your page:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://www.jplayer.org/latest/js/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I was super psyched for this because I was having an issue with playing music on the iPad. And in the test you posted on jsfiddle.net it doesn't pull up an audio player, which is exactly what I want BUT when I did it on just a simple HTML page it pulled up a player. What did I do wrong?

I can't seem to post all the code here but yo can check it out at:
[link]www.feefifofun.com/music.html[link]

Any help would be appreciated!